# GD Library - How to use via commandline? Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, gd

Is there any way to use [GD](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) to convert images via the commandline? I need to do a comparison of output quality between GD and Imagemagick.

I've installed `php5-gd` and `libgd-tools` but can't seem to find any information on how to run a simple compression/resize using GD and the commandline. (Is it even possible?)

I am running Ubuntu 12.10